# Invalid appsecret_proof provided (django Rest framework)

Tags: django-rest-framework

[image]

Getting this error (using social_django) i.e. load_backend, load strategy on Facebook login.

How can I remove the `appsecret_proof` from URL if possible, because when I hit the URL without `appsecret_proof`? It gives response 200.
The graph Facebook URL is automated generated by Facebook, I guess.
P.S: The same API is working for Google Login

The error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "A3pQN70RqFZz5j2i2zheaxd"
   }
}
```

Comment: Please include the text of the API response instead of including it as an image.

Comment: {
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "A3pQN70RqFZz5j2i2zheaxd"
   }
}